# How to Make MediaElement.js Fluid?

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I've been playing around with the code and I can't seem to get this to work. I've googled, searched on this site looking through 13 pages and I still can't find the answer to what I'm looking for.

I want to have a video start out with a specific dimension and then scale down as I resize the browser (going from desktop to iPad/iPhone).

I've tried doing the below, but the video stays the same. Nothing scales.

```
<div id="myVideo" style="width:640px; height:360px">
    <video id="player1" width="100%" height="100%" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <!-- Pseudo HTML5 -->
        <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />
    </video>
</div>
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: This might be useful - http://fitvidsjs.com/. Also, you might want to consider media queries - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Tried that. I'm down to media queries at this point, but my media query for smartphones is not working. This example is not working when I resize the browser: '@media only screen and (min-width : 320px )and (max-width : 480px)'

Answer (score 11):

set your video node's height/width attributes to the original video size, but keep the style width/height at 100% like this

```
<video id="player1" width="640px" height="360px" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

then resize your myVideo div as necessary and mejs should respond as expected

Comment: Weird answer, but it worked for me.  It was already working in Chrome just by setting the video attribute width / height (in pixels), but for some reason not in Firefox.  Adding CSS width/height 100% made it so that I can dynamically resize the video.  Thanks!

Comment: It's enough and better though just to add to *<video>* tag `width="100%" height="100%" ` with out style attribute. Then the video will be both width and height fluid.

Comment: This has worked for me. Its a hack. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872915/mediaelement-js-responsive-video-with-fixed-max-size/34511368#34511368

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a specific size (640px 360px) set on the #myVideo div, so the video element inside is 100% of that box. If you remove the pixel dimensions - or try changing them to max- -- it should be scalable.

Comment: This doesn't work with MediaElement.js (what the OP is using). It can only handle fixed dimensions.

Comment: Its hack, but have worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872915/mediaelement-js-responsive-video-with-fixed-max-size/34511368#34511368

Answer (score 0):

This works.  The width = "50%" in the myvids div is there for IE.  Without it the video does not properly fill the player.  Order of the video attributes really seems to matter.

```
<div class="myvids" id="viddivap1" width="50%" style="width:100%; position:relative;">
    <video class="thevid" width="640" height="360" style="max-width:100%; height:100%;" id="my_video_ap1" preload="auto" autoplay controls="controls" >
        <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAGL9gxhdHM" />
    </video>
</div>
```